# Solr warming cache after delta import with Data Import Handler

Tags: caching, solr, faceted-search

My Solr index gets updated with DIH every hour. But after this delta import, the facet query's execution is extremely slow. (over 20 seconds)

I tried to set the autowarmCount of filterCache, queryResultCache, and documentCache and also use a newSearcher and firstSearcher Event Listener to fire the same query after every import. But the query executions after are still at about 10 seconds.
When I fire the same query manually 2 or 3 times in a row, its execution time is under one second.

What do miss? Why are the effects of the execution of a query with the newSearcher and firstSearcher Event Listener different to the manual execution of a query?

Answer (score 0):

Can you send here newSearcher queries and query which takes 20 seconds to run?
Do you use `<useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>`?

Comment: I tried `<useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>` and `<useColdSearcher>true</useColdSearcher>` but made no difference

Comment: an example for my query would be:
`q=*:*
&rows=0
&fl=name,timestamp
&fq=name:["" TO *]
&fq=-attributes:["" TO *]
&fq=first:0
&fq=rank:0
&facet=true
&facet.field={!key=searchQuery}name
&f.name.facet.mincount=1`

Comment: If it is a signle query why just not to run `q=*:*&facet=true&facet.field={!key=searchQuery}name`. Moreover I would suggest to run queries for all fields you use for faceting, sorting and add some frequent filters.

Please also provide us with information about your cache settings and statistics (current size, evictions, hit ratio).